# ¿Cómo adaptar controles personalizados en vídeo media player - jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css3

Estoy implementando un diseño de controles de vídeos personalizados, teniendo algo de errores en adaptarlo existe un desorden en el diseño.

Cómo puedo adaptar el diseño responsiva y estructurarlos de manera correcta que quede en un orden perfecto similar a la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el diseño del **Speed** añadir un circulo azul que indique en que velocidad se ha seleccionado la velocidad del vídeo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **Nota 1:** Imágenes adicionales necesarias para animar el audio actualmente se esta animando 3 tipos de audio el `silencio` el `volumen 1` y el `volumen 3` faltaría poder añadir el volumen 2 http://svgshare.com/i/3uH.svg.
>
> **Nota 2:** Imagen adicional para quitar la pantalla completa http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg, solo esta incluida la imagen `full screen`.

**Código completo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //INITIALIZE
 var video = $('#myVideo');
 
 //remove default control when JS loaded
 video[0].removeAttribute("controls");
 $('.control').show().css({'bottom':-45});
 $('.loading').fadeIn(500);
 $('.caption').fadeIn(500);
 
 //before everything get started
 video.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
  $('.caption').animate({'top':-45},300);
   
  //set video properties
  $('.current').text(timeFormat(0));
  $('.duration').text(timeFormat(video[0].duration));
  updateVolume(0, 0.7);
   
  //start to get video buffering data 
  setTimeout(startBuffer, 150);
   
  //bind video events
  $('.videoContainer')
  .append('<div id="init"></div>')
  .hover(function() {
   $('.control').stop().animate({'bottom':0}, 500);
   $('.caption').stop().animate({'top':0}, 500);
  }, function() {
   if(!volumeDrag && !timeDrag){
    $('.control').stop().animate({'bottom':-45}, 500);
    $('.caption').stop().animate({'top':-45}, 500);
   }
  })
  .on('click', function() {
   $('#init').remove();
   $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
   $(this).unbind('click');
   video[0].play();
  });
  $('#init').fadeIn(200);
 });
 
 //display video buffering bar
 var startBuffer = function() {
  var currentBuffer = video[0].buffered.end(0);
  var maxduration = video[0].duration;
  var perc = 100 * currentBuffer / maxduration;
  $('.bufferBar').css('width',perc+'%');
   
  if(currentBuffer < maxduration) {
   setTimeout(startBuffer, 500);
  }
 }; 
 
 //display current video play time
 video.on('timeupdate', function() {
  var currentPos = video[0].currentTime;
  var maxduration = video[0].duration;
  var perc = 100 * currentPos / maxduration;
  $('.timeBar').css('width',perc+'%'); 
  $('.current').text(timeFormat(currentPos)); 
 });
 
 //CONTROLS EVENTS
 //video screen and play button clicked
 video.on('click', function() { playpause(); } );
 $('.btnPlay').on('click', function() { playpause(); } );
 var playpause = function() {
  if(video[0].paused || video[0].ended) {
   $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
   video[0].play();
  }
  else {
   $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
   video[0].pause();
  }
 };
 
 //speed text clicked
 $('.btnx1').on('click', function() { fastfowrd(this, 1); });
 $('.btnx3').on('click', function() { fastfowrd(this, 3); });
 var fastfowrd = function(obj, spd) {
  $('.text').removeClass('selected');
  $(obj).addClass('selected');
  video[0].playbackRate = spd;
  video[0].play();
 };
 
 //stop button clicked
 $('.btnStop').on('click', function() {
  $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
  updatebar($('.progress').offset().left);
  video[0].pause();
 });
 
 //fullscreen button clicked
 $('.btnFS').on('click', function() {
  if($.isFunction(video[0].webkitEnterFullscreen)) {
   video[0].webkitEnterFullscreen();
  } 
  else if ($.isFunction(video[0].mozRequestFullScreen)) {
   video[0].mozRequestFullScreen();
  }
  else {
   alert('Your browsers doesn\'t support fullscreen');
  }
 });
 
 //sound button clicked
 $('.sound').click(function() {
  video[0].muted = !video[0].muted;
  $(this).toggleClass('muted');
  if(video[0].muted) {
   $('.volumeBar').css('width',0);
  }
  else{
   $('.volumeBar').css('width', video[0].volume*100+'%');
  }
 });
 
 //VIDEO EVENTS
 //video canplay event
 video.on('canplay', function() {
  $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
 });
 
 //video canplaythrough event
 //solve Chrome cache issue
 var completeloaded = false;
 video.on('canplaythrough', function() {
  completeloaded = true;
 });
 
 //video ended event
 video.on('ended', function() {
  $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
  video[0].pause();
 });

 //video seeking event
 video.on('seeking', function() {
  //if video fully loaded, ignore loading screen
  if(!completeloaded) { 
   $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
  } 
 });
 
 //video seeked event
 video.on('seeked', function() { });
 
 //video waiting for more data event
 video.on('waiting', function() {
  $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
 });
 
 //VIDEO PROGRESS BAR
 //when video timebar clicked
 var timeDrag = false; /* check for drag event */
 $('.progress').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  timeDrag = true;
  updatebar(e.pageX);
 });
 $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  if(timeDrag) {
   timeDrag = false;
   updatebar(e.pageX);
  }
 });
 $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  if(timeDrag) {
   updatebar(e.pageX);
  }
 });
 var updatebar = function(x) {
  var progress = $('.progress');
  
  //calculate drag position
  //and update video currenttime
  //as well as progress bar
  var maxduration = video[0].duration;
  var position = x - progress.offset().left;
  var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();
  if(percentage > 100) {
   percentage = 100;
  }
  if(percentage < 0) {
   percentage = 0;
  }
  $('.timeBar').css('width',percentage+'%'); 
  video[0].currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
 };

 //VOLUME BAR
 //volume bar event
 var volumeDrag = false;
 $('.volume').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  volumeDrag = true;
  video[0].muted = false;
  $('.sound').removeClass('muted');
  updateVolume(e.pageX);
 });
 $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  if(volumeDrag) {
   volumeDrag = false;
   updateVolume(e.pageX);
  }
 });
 $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  if(volumeDrag) {
   updateVolume(e.pageX);
  }
 });
 var updateVolume = function(x, vol) {
  var volume = $('.volume');
  var percentage;
  //if only volume have specificed
  //then direct update volume
  if(vol) {
   percentage = vol * 100;
  }
  else {
   var position = x - volume.offset().left;
   percentage = 100 * position / volume.width();
  }
  
  if(percentage > 100) {
   percentage = 100;
  }
  if(percentage < 0) {
   percentage = 0;
  }
  
  //update volume bar and video volume
  $('.volumeBar').css('width',percentage+'%'); 
  video[0].volume = percentage / 100;
  
  //change sound icon based on volume
  if(video[0].volume == 0){
   $('.sound').removeClass('sound2').addClass('muted');
  }
  else if(video[0].volume > 0.5){
   $('.sound').removeClass('muted').addClass('sound2');
  }
  else{
   $('.sound').removeClass('muted').removeClass('sound2');
  }
  
 };

 //Time format converter - 00:00
 var timeFormat = function(seconds){
  var m = Math.floor(seconds/60)<10 ? "0"+Math.floor(seconds/60) : Math.floor(seconds/60);
  var s = Math.floor(seconds-(m*60))<10 ? "0"+Math.floor(seconds-(m*60)) : Math.floor(seconds-(m*60));
  return m+":"+s;
 };
});
```

```css
/* video container */
.videoContainer{
 width:600px;
 height:350px;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 background:#000;
 color:#ccc;
}

/* video caption css */
.caption{
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 padding:10px;
 color:#ccc;
 font-size:20px;
 font-weight:bold;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #1F1F1F; /* fallback */
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#242424 50%,#1F1F1F 50%,#171717 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#242424 50%,#1F1F1F 50%,#171717 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#242424 50%,#1F1F1F 50%,#171717 100%);
}

/*** VIDEO CONTROLS CSS ***/
/* control holder */
.control{
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
  height: 45px;
 /*height: 13%;*/
 z-index:5;
 display:none;
}

/* control top part */
.topControl {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

/* control bottom part */
.btmControl{
 clear:both;
 background: #1F1F1F; /* fallback */
 background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#242424 50%,#1F1F1F 50%,#171717 100%);
 background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#242424 50%,#1F1F1F 50%,#171717 100%);
 background:-o-linear-gradient(top,#242424 50%,#1F1F1F 50%,#171717 100%);
}

.control .btn {
 float:left;
 width:34px;
 height:30px;
 padding:0 10px;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.control div.btnPlay::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3um.svg);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
}

/*
.control div.paused{
}
*/

.control div.paused::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3vz.svg);
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  left: -10px;
}

.control div.spdText {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: #29303b;
  background-color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.9);
}

.speed {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.speed-title {
 text-align: left;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.speed li {
 padding: 5px 20px 5px 15px;
}

.speed .btnx3:hover, .btnx1:hover {
 background-color: #505763;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.spdText:hover .speed {
 text-align: center;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 1s;
  left:-25px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white;
  top: -102px;
}

.control div.selected{
 font-size:15px;
 color:#ccc;
}

.control div.sound::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ww.svg);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  /*left: -10px;*/
}

.control div.sound2::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3xS.svg);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  /*left: -10px;*/
}

.control div.muted::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3v_.svg);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
}

.control div.btnFS{
 float: right;
}

.control div.btnFS::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3wo.svg); 
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
}

/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */
/* Progress bar */
.progress {
 width:85%;
 height:10px;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.progress span {
 height:40%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:block;
}

.timeBar{
 z-index:10;
 width:0;
 background: #2EB3D0;
}

.bufferBar{
 z-index:5;
 width:0;
 background: #ddd;
}

/* time and duration */
.time{
 float:right;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:11px;
 line-height:12px;
}

/* VOLUME BAR CSS */
/* volume bar */
.volume{
 position:relative;
 cursor:pointer;
 width:70px;
 height:10px;
 float:right;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
}

.volumeBar{
 display:block;
 height:40%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background-color:#eee;
 z-index:10;
}

/* OTHERS CSS */
/* video screen cover */
.loading, #init{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
 z-index:2;
 display:none;
}

#init{
 background:url(bigplay.png) no-repeat 50% 50% !important;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Content -->
<section id="wrapper">

<div class="videoContainer">
 
 <video id="myVideo" controls preload="auto" poster="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/x676X3ak3wo/maxresdefault.jpg" width="600" height="350" >
   <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="http://demo.inwebson.com/html5-video/iceage4.webm" type="video/webM" />
   <source src="http://demo.inwebson.com/html5-video/iceage4.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
   <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
 </video>
 <div class="caption">This is HTML5 video with custom controls</div>
 <div class="control">

  <div class="btmControl">
   <div class="btnPlay btn" title="Play/Pause video"></div>
   <!--<div class="btnStop btn" title="Stop video"></div>-->
   <div class="spdText btn">x1
     <ul class="speed">
       <li class="speed-title">Speed</li>
       <li class="btnx3">x3</li>
       <li class="btnx1 selected">x1</li>
        </ul>
   </div>

   <!--<div class="btnx1 btn text selected" title="Normal speed">x1</div>
   <div class="btnx3 btn text" title="Fast forward x3">x3</div>-->

  <div class="topControl">
   <div class="progress">
    <span class="bufferBar"></span>
    <span class="timeBar"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="time">
    <span class="current"></span> / 
    <span class="duration"></span> 
   </div>
  </div>

   <div class="btnFS btn" title="Switch to full screen"></div>
   <!--<div class="btnLight lighton btn" title="Turn on/off light"></div>-->
   <div class="volume" title="Set volume">
    <span class="volumeBar"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="sound sound2 btn" title="Mute/Unmute sound"></div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
 <div class="loading"></div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Me sigue faltando información: Tienes dos fragmentos de código, el primero que muestra los elementos mal colocados y el segundo que está mucho mejor... ¿Qué es lo que hay que arreglar?

Comment: @PabloLozano Ya he añadido los detalles y corregido nuevas cosas espero ahora este detallado mejor la información saludos.

Comment: Hola So12 , puedo aconsejarte otra forma mas simple de hacerlo ? , este código que pones lo has hecho tu?

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que quieres hacer? No me termina de quedar claro.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro crees poder hacer algo no importa si no es todo lo solicitado puede ser cierta parte de algo lo importante es el aporte aunque sea solo el diseño o otro... Gracias! :)

Comment: El círculo azul de velocidad lo he solucionado. No me quedaba claro cuáles eran las otras cosas. Entonces lo que quieres solucionar es 1) volumen. 2) velocidad. Y 3) icono de pantalla completa. ¿Correcto?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si amigo añadir el volúmen 2, y el icono de quitar pantalla completa cuándo se haga full screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si he comprendido bien por la pregunta y los comentarios, realmente lo que quieres hacer son estas tres cosas:

1. La velocidad debe mostrar un círculo azul que indique cuál está activa.
2. Cambiar el icono cuando se está en pantalla completa.
3. El volumen tiene que tener un nivel más.

Vamos a ver las tres cosas por separado y al final las ponemos juntas en el código.

---

**Indicador de velocidad**

El círculo azul se puede añadir fácilmente con CSS, pero aparte hay otro problema con el código JavaScript que hace que no se desactive la opción oportuna. Así que hay que corregir esas dos cosas.

El código JS que tienes ahora mismo es éste:

```
  //speed text clicked
  $('.btnx1').on('click', function() {
    fastfowrd(this, 1);
  });
  $('.btnx3').on('click', function() {
    fastfowrd(this, 3);
  });
  var fastfowrd = function(obj, spd) {
    $('.text').removeClass('selected');
    $(obj).addClass('selected');
    video[0].playbackRate = spd;
    video[0].play();
  };
```

Esta parte es incorrecta: `$('.text').removeClass('selected');`. El selector `.text` no devuelve nada así que no desactivará nada (al menos no se le quitará la clase selected a nada). Parece que esto es código antiguo porque hay comentado algo que sí tenía la clase `text`. La solución es simple, cambia el selector para que se quite el `.selected` a la clase `.selected` de esa lista.

```
    $('.speed .selected').removeClass('selected');
```

Y ahora que sabes que la clase selected se va a aplicar/quitar correctamente, puedes estilizar el punto haciendo algo como esto:

```
.speed li { position: relative; }
.speed li.selected::after {
  content: "·";
  color: #00ffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

---

**Pantalla completa**

Cambiar el icono para pantalla completa es algo que vamos a hacer con CSS también, pero antes vamos a ver tu código JS:

```
  //fullscreen button clicked
  $('.btnFS').on('click', function() {
    if ($.isFunction(video[0].webkitEnterFullscreen)) {
      video[0].webkitEnterFullscreen();
    } else if ($.isFunction(video[0].mozRequestFullScreen)) {
      video[0].mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else {
      alert('Your browsers doesn\'t support fullscreen');
    }
  });
```

...este código tiene problemas que harán que falle de todos modos:

1. Estás haciendo pantalla completa del vídeo, eso es un problema porque cuando el video se ponga en pantalla completa, tus nuevos controles ya no se verán. Lo que quieres hacer es que lo que se ponga a pantalla completa sea el `div` que contiene el vídeo.
2. Controlas que se entre en pantalla completa (que es cuando deberías cambiar el icono), pero no controlas cuando se sale (que es cuando deberías volver a poner el icono original en su lugar).
3. El código JS tiene errores. Por ejemplo `webkitEnterFullscreen` no es una función válida, querrías `webkitRequestFullscreen` (como en moz)

Arreglando esas tres cosas (y limpiando un poco, porque es complejo), se vería así:

```
  //fullscreen button clicked
  $('.btnFS').on('click', function() {
    // si estamos en modo de pantalla completa
    if (document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement) {
      // salimos del modo de pantalla completa
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      }
    } else {
      // si no, entramos en modo pantalla completa
      element = $('#wrapper').get(0);
      if (element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {            
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) { 
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();            
      } else {
        alert('Your browsers doesn\'t support fullscreen');
      }
    }
  });
```

Y para controlar que el icono cambia, se puede usar los selectores especiales de pantalla completa (por separado porque si se ponen juntas y los navegadores detectan un error en una, ignorarán todas):

```
:-webkit-full-screen .control div.btnFS::after { background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg) ; }
:-moz-full-screen .control div.btnFS::after { background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg) ; }
:-ms-fullscreen .control div.btnFS::after { background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg) ; }
:fullscreen .control div.btnFS::after { background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg) ; }
```

Lamentablemente, el modo de ejecución de scripts de StackOverflow impide que se pueda poner el vídeo a pantalla completa, pero he probado y funciona.

> Nota: me he limitado a cambiar lo menos posible tu código para
>   adaptarme a lo preguntado. Pero sería interesante que cuando lo
>   cambies a pantalla completa, hagas que el vídeo ocupe un 100% de la
>   pantalla, de lo contrario estará limitado a los 600x350 que le tienes
>   puesto.

---

**Volumen de nivel 2**

Ahora, para el volumen tienes un sistema que dependiendo del valor quitará/añadirá clases para que se muestre un icono u otro:

```
    //change sound icon based on volume
    if (video[0].volume == 0) {
      $('.sound').removeClass('sound2').addClass('muted');
    } else if (video[0].volume > 0.5) {
      $('.sound').removeClass('muted').addClass('sound2');
    } else {
      $('.sound').removeClass('muted').removeClass('sound2');
    }
```

Lo único que tendrías que hacer es añadir un control más. Ahora en lugar de romperse en tres niveles (0, 0-50 o 50-100), tendrás que romper en 4 niveles (0, 0-33, 33-66, 66-100... puedes cambiar estos valores como quieras para ajustar los iconos a lo que quieras).

Con ese cambio, quedaría así (uniendo todos los `removeClass` en uno sólo por línea):

```
    //change sound icon based on volume
    if (video[0].volume == 0) {
      $('.sound').removeClass('sound2, sound3').addClass('muted');
    } else if (video[0].volume > 0.6) {
      $('.sound').removeClass('muted, sound3').addClass('sound2');
    } else if (video[0].volume > 0.3) {
      $('.sound').removeClass('muted, sound2').addClass('sound3');
    } else {
      $('.sound').removeClass('muted, sound2, sound3');
    }
```

Y sólo te quedaría añadir el nuevo CSS (que será igual al de .sound2 sólo cambiando la imagen):

```
.control div.sound2::after,
.control div.sound3::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3xS.svg);
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  /*left: -10px;*/
}

.control div.sound3::after {
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3uH.svg);
}
```

---

Y finalmente el código completo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //INITIALIZE
  var video = $('#myVideo');

  //remove default control when JS loaded
  video[0].removeAttribute("controls");
  $('.control').show().css({
    'bottom': -45
  });
  $('.loading').fadeIn(500);
  $('.caption').fadeIn(500);

  //before everything get started
  video.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
    $('.caption').animate({
      'top': -45
    }, 300);

    //set video properties
    $('.current').text(timeFormat(0));
    $('.duration').text(timeFormat(video[0].duration));
    updateVolume(0, 0.7);

    //start to get video buffering data 
    setTimeout(startBuffer, 150);

    //bind video events
    $('.videoContainer')
      .append('<div id="init"></div>')
      .hover(function() {
        $('.control').stop().animate({
          'bottom': 0
        }, 500);
        $('.caption').stop().animate({
          'top': 0
        }, 500);
      }, function() {
        if (!volumeDrag && !timeDrag) {
          $('.control').stop().animate({
            'bottom': -45
          }, 500);
          $('.caption').stop().animate({
            'top': -45
          }, 500);
        }
      })
      .on('click', function() {
        $('#init').remove();
        $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
        $(this).unbind('click');
        video[0].play();
      });
    $('#init').fadeIn(200);
  });

  //display video buffering bar
  var startBuffer = function() {
    var currentBuffer = video[0].buffered.end(0);
    var maxduration = video[0].duration;
    var perc = 100 * currentBuffer / maxduration;
    $('.bufferBar').css('width', perc + '%');

    if (currentBuffer < maxduration) {
      setTimeout(startBuffer, 500);
    }
  };

  //display current video play time
  video.on('timeupdate', function() {
    var currentPos = video[0].currentTime;
    var maxduration = video[0].duration;
    var perc = 100 * currentPos / maxduration;
    $('.timeBar').css('width', perc + '%');
    $('.current').text(timeFormat(currentPos));
  });

  //CONTROLS EVENTS
  //video screen and play button clicked
  video.on('click', function() {
    playpause();
  });
  $('.btnPlay').on('click', function() {
    playpause();
  });
  var playpause = function() {
    if (video[0].paused || video[0].ended) {
      $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
      video[0].play();
    } else {
      $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
      video[0].pause();
    }
  };

  //speed text clicked
  $('.btn-speed').on('click', function() {
    spd = $(this).data("speed");
    $('.speed .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    video[0].playbackRate = spd;
    //video[0].play();
    $("#current-speed").text("x" + spd);
  });

  //stop button clicked
  $('.btnStop').on('click', function() {
    $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
    updatebar($('.progress').offset().left);
    video[0].pause();
  });

  //fullscreen button clicked
  $('.btnFS').on('click', function() {
    // si estamos en modo de pantalla completa
    if (document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement) {
      // salimos del modo de pantalla completa
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      }
    } else {
      // si no, entramos en modo pantalla completa
      element = $('#wrapper').get(0);
      if (element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      } else {
        alert('Your browsers doesn\'t support fullscreen');
      }
    }
  });


  //sound button clicked
  $('.sound').click(function() {
    video[0].muted = !video[0].muted;
    $(this).toggleClass('muted');
    if (video[0].muted) {
      $('.volumeBar').css('width', 0);
    } else {
      $('.volumeBar').css('width', video[0].volume * 100 + '%');
    }
  });

  //VIDEO EVENTS
  //video canplay event
  video.on('canplay', function() {
    $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
  });

  //video canplaythrough event
  //solve Chrome cache issue
  var completeloaded = false;
  video.on('canplaythrough', function() {
    completeloaded = true;
  });

  //video ended event
  video.on('ended', function() {
    $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
    video[0].pause();
  });

  //video seeking event
  video.on('seeking', function() {
    //if video fully loaded, ignore loading screen
    if (!completeloaded) {
      $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
    }
  });

  //video seeked event
  video.on('seeked', function() {});

  //video waiting for more data event
  video.on('waiting', function() {
    $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
  });

  //VIDEO PROGRESS BAR
  //when video timebar clicked
  var timeDrag = false; /* check for drag event */
  $('.progress').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    timeDrag = true;
    updatebar(e.pageX);
  });
  $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    if (timeDrag) {
      timeDrag = false;
      updatebar(e.pageX);
    }
  });
  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (timeDrag) {
      updatebar(e.pageX);
    }
  });
  var updatebar = function(x) {
    var progress = $('.progress');

    //calculate drag position
    //and update video currenttime
    //as well as progress bar
    var maxduration = video[0].duration;
    var position = x - progress.offset().left;
    var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();
    if (percentage > 100) {
      percentage = 100;
    }
    if (percentage < 0) {
      percentage = 0;
    }
    $('.timeBar').css('width', percentage + '%');
    video[0].currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
  };

  //VOLUME BAR
  //volume bar event
  var volumeDrag = false;
  $('.volume').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    volumeDrag = true;
    video[0].muted = false;
    $('.sound').removeClass('muted');
    updateVolume(e.pageX);
  });
  $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    if (volumeDrag) {
      volumeDrag = false;
      updateVolume(e.pageX);
    }
  });
  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (volumeDrag) {
      updateVolume(e.pageX);
    }
  });
  var updateVolume = function(x, vol) {
    var volume = $('.volume');
    var percentage;
    //if only volume have specificed
    //then direct update volume
    if (vol) {
      percentage = vol * 100;
    } else {
      var position = x - volume.offset().left;
      percentage = 100 * position / volume.width();
    }

    if (percentage > 100) {
      percentage = 100;
    }
    if (percentage < 0) {
      percentage = 0;
    }

    //update volume bar and video volume
    $('.volumeBar').css('width', percentage + '%');
    video[0].volume = percentage / 100;

//change sound icon based on volume
        if (video[0].volume == 0) {
          $('.sound').removeClass('sound2, sound3').addClass('muted');
        } else if (video[0].volume > 0.66) {
          $('.sound').removeClass('muted, sound3').addClass('sound2');
        } else if (video[0].volume > 0.33) {
          $('.sound').removeClass('muted, sound2').addClass('sound3');
        } else {
          $('.sound').removeClass('muted, sound2, sound3');
        }

  };

  //Time format converter - 00:00
  var timeFormat = function(seconds) {
    var m = Math.floor(seconds / 60) < 10 ? "0" + Math.floor(seconds / 60) : Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(seconds - (m * 60)) < 10 ? "0" + Math.floor(seconds - (m * 60)) : Math.floor(seconds - (m * 60));
    return m + ":" + s;
  };
});
```

```css
/** CODIGO NUEVO *****************/

.speed li {
  position: relative;
}

.speed li.selected::after {
  content: "·";
  color: #00ffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 36px;
}

:-webkit-full-screen .control div.btnFS::after {
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg);
}

:-moz-full-screen .control div.btnFS::after {
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg);
}

:-ms-fullscreen .control div.btnFS::after {
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg);
}

:fullscreen .control div.btnFS::after {
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg);
}

/* hay algo más de código nuevo abajo junto a .sound2 */

/** CODIGO ORIGINAL **************/


/* video container */

.videoContainer {
  width: 600px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  color: #ccc;
}


/* video caption css */

.caption {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #1F1F1F;
  /* fallback */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
}


/*** VIDEO CONTROLS CSS ***/


/* control holder */

.control {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  /*height: 13%;*/
  z-index: 5;
  display: none;
}


/* control top part */

.topControl {
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 16px;
}


/* control bottom part */

.btmControl {
  height: 100%;
  clear: both;
  background: #1F1F1F;
  /* fallback */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
  display: flex;
}

.control .btn {
  width: 34px;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.control .btn::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
}

.control div.btnPlay::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3um.svg);
}


/*
.control div.paused{
}
*/

.control div.paused::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3vz.svg);
}

.control div.spdText {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: #29303b;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9);
  top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.speed {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.speed-title {
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

.speed li {
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 15px;
}

.speed .btn-speed:hover {
  background-color: #505763;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.spdText:hover .speed {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 1s;
  left: -25px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white;
  bottom: 24px;
}

.control div.selected {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ccc;
}

.control div.sound::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ww.svg);
}

/* código nuevo */
.control div.sound2::after,
.control div.sound3::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3xS.svg);
}

/* código nuevo */
.control div.sound3::after {
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3uH.svg);
}


.control div.muted::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3v_.svg);
}

.control div.btnFS {
  float: right;
}

.control div.btnFS::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3wo.svg);
}


/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */


/* Progress bar */

.progress {
  width: 85%;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.progress span {
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.timeBar {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 0;
  background: #2EB3D0;
}

.bufferBar {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}


/* time and duration */

.time {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 12px;
}


/* VOLUME BAR CSS */


/* volume bar */

.volume {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 70px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.volumeBar {
  display: block;
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  z-index: 10;
}


/* OTHERS CSS */


/* video screen cover */

.loading,
#init {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}

#init {
  background: url(bigplay.png) no-repeat 50% 50% !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Content -->
<section id="wrapper">

  <div class="videoContainer">

    <video id="myVideo" controls preload="auto" poster="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/x676X3ak3wo/maxresdefault.jpg" width="600" height="350">
   <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="http://demo.inwebson.com/html5-video/iceage4.webm" type="video/webM" />
   <source src="http://demo.inwebson.com/html5-video/iceage4.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
   <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
 </video>
    <div class="caption">This is HTML5 video with custom controls</div>
    <div class="control">

      <div class="btmControl">
        <div class="btnPlay btn" title="Play/Pause video"></div>
        <!--<div class="btnStop btn" title="Stop video"></div>-->
        <div class="spdText btn"><span id="current-speed">x1</span>
          <ul class="speed">
            <li class="speed-title">Speed</li>
            <li data-speed="3" class="btn-speed btnx3">x3</li>
            <li data-speed="2" class="btn-speed btnx2">x2</li>
            <li data-speed="1" class="btn-speed btnx1 selected">x1</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <!--<div class="btnx1 btn text selected" title="Normal speed">x1</div>
   <div class="btnx3 btn text" title="Fast forward x3">x3</div>-->

        <div class="topControl">
          <div class="progress">
            <span class="bufferBar"></span>
            <span class="timeBar"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="time">
            <span class="current"></span> /
            <span class="duration"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        
        <!--<div class="btnLight lighton btn" title="Turn on/off light"></div>-->
        <div class="sound sound2 btn" title="Mute/Unmute sound"></div>
        <div class="volume" title="Set volume">
          <span class="volumeBar"></span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="btnFS btn" title="Switch to full screen"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="loading"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Subilo a algún hosting gratuito... ¡Queremos verlo en acción! :-)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69113/discussion-between-so12-and-alvaro-montoro).

Answer (score 3):

Buenas acomode el `css` para que se vea todo mucho mejor y ordenado saludos espero que te ayude y sea lo que buscas

aqui el codepen por si quieres editar o verlo mejor

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/lusaxweb/pen/WXyxJq)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //INITIALIZE
  var video = $('#myVideo');

  //remove default control when JS loaded
  video[0].removeAttribute("controls");
  $('.control').show().css({
    'bottom': -45
  });
  $('.loading').fadeIn(500);
  $('.caption').fadeIn(500);

  //before everything get started
  video.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
    $('.caption').animate({
      'top': -45
    }, 300);

    //set video properties
    $('.current').text(timeFormat(0));
    $('.duration').text(timeFormat(video[0].duration));
    updateVolume(0, 0.7);

    //start to get video buffering data 
    setTimeout(startBuffer, 150);

    //bind video events
    $('.videoContainer')
      .append('<div id="init"></div>')
      .hover(function() {
        $('.control').stop().animate({
          'bottom': 0
        }, 500);
        $('.caption').stop().animate({
          'top': 0
        }, 500);
      }, function() {
        if (!volumeDrag && !timeDrag) {
          $('.control').stop().animate({
            'bottom': -45
          }, 500);
          $('.caption').stop().animate({
            'top': -45
          }, 500);
        }
      })
      .on('click', function() {
        $('#init').remove();
        $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
        $(this).unbind('click');
        video[0].play();
      });
    $('#init').fadeIn(200);
  });

  //display video buffering bar
  var startBuffer = function() {
    var currentBuffer = video[0].buffered.end(0);
    var maxduration = video[0].duration;
    var perc = 100 * currentBuffer / maxduration;
    $('.bufferBar').css('width', perc + '%');

    if (currentBuffer < maxduration) {
      setTimeout(startBuffer, 500);
    }
  };

  //display current video play time
  video.on('timeupdate', function() {
    var currentPos = video[0].currentTime;
    var maxduration = video[0].duration;
    var perc = 100 * currentPos / maxduration;
    $('.timeBar').css('width', perc + '%');
    $('.current').text(timeFormat(currentPos));
  });

  //CONTROLS EVENTS
  //video screen and play button clicked
  video.on('click', function() {
    playpause();
  });
  $('.btnPlay').on('click', function() {
    playpause();
  });
  var playpause = function() {
    if (video[0].paused || video[0].ended) {
      $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
      video[0].play();
    } else {
      $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
      video[0].pause();
    }
  };

  //speed text clicked
  $('.btn-speed').on('click', function() {
    spd = $(this).data("speed");
    $('.speed .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    video[0].playbackRate = spd;
    video[0].play();
    $("#current-speed").text("x" + spd);
  });

  //stop button clicked
  $('.btnStop').on('click', function() {
    $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
    updatebar($('.progress').offset().left);
    video[0].pause();
  });

  //fullscreen button clicked
  $('.btnFS').on('click', function() {
    // si estamos en modo de pantalla completa
    if (document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement) {
      // salimos del modo de pantalla completa
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      }
    } else {
      // si no, entramos en modo pantalla completa
      element = $('#wrapper').get(0);
      if (element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      } else {
        alert('Your browsers doesn\'t support fullscreen');
      }
    }
  });


  //sound button clicked
  $('.sound').click(function() {
    video[0].muted = !video[0].muted;
    $(this).toggleClass('muted');
    if (video[0].muted) {
      $('.volumeBar').css('width', 0);
    } else {
      $('.volumeBar').css('width', video[0].volume * 100 + '%');
    }
  });

  //VIDEO EVENTS
  //video canplay event
  video.on('canplay', function() {
    $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
  });

  //video canplaythrough event
  //solve Chrome cache issue
  var completeloaded = false;
  video.on('canplaythrough', function() {
    completeloaded = true;
  });

  //video ended event
  video.on('ended', function() {
    $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
    video[0].pause();
  });

  //video seeking event
  video.on('seeking', function() {
    //if video fully loaded, ignore loading screen
    if (!completeloaded) {
      $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
    }
  });

  //video seeked event
  video.on('seeked', function() {});

  //video waiting for more data event
  video.on('waiting', function() {
    $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
  });

  //VIDEO PROGRESS BAR
  //when video timebar clicked
  var timeDrag = false; /* check for drag event */
  $('.progress').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    timeDrag = true;
    updatebar(e.pageX);
  });
  $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    if (timeDrag) {
      timeDrag = false;
      updatebar(e.pageX);
    }
  });
  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (timeDrag) {
      updatebar(e.pageX);
    }
  });
  var updatebar = function(x) {
    var progress = $('.progress');

    //calculate drag position
    //and update video currenttime
    //as well as progress bar
    var maxduration = video[0].duration;
    var position = x - progress.offset().left;
    var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();
    if (percentage > 100) {
      percentage = 100;
    }
    if (percentage < 0) {
      percentage = 0;
    }
    $('.timeBar').css('width', percentage + '%');
    video[0].currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
  };

  //VOLUME BAR
  //volume bar event
  var volumeDrag = false;
  $('.volume').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    volumeDrag = true;
    video[0].muted = false;
    $('.sound').removeClass('muted');
    updateVolume(e.pageX);
  });
  $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    if (volumeDrag) {
      volumeDrag = false;
      updateVolume(e.pageX);
    }
  });
  $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (volumeDrag) {
      updateVolume(e.pageX);
    }
  });
  var updateVolume = function(x, vol) {
    var volume = $('.volume');
    var percentage;
    //if only volume have specificed
    //then direct update volume
    if (vol) {
      percentage = vol * 100;
    } else {
      var position = x - volume.offset().left;
      percentage = 100 * position / volume.width();
    }

    if (percentage > 100) {
      percentage = 100;
    }
    if (percentage < 0) {
      percentage = 0;
    }

    //update volume bar and video volume
    $('.volumeBar').css('width', percentage + '%');
    video[0].volume = percentage / 100;

//change sound icon based on volume
        if (video[0].volume == 0) {
          $('.sound').removeClass('sound2, sound3').addClass('muted');
        } else if (video[0].volume > 0.66) {
          $('.sound').removeClass('muted, sound3').addClass('sound2');
        } else if (video[0].volume > 0.33) {
          $('.sound').removeClass('muted, sound2').addClass('sound3');
        } else {
          $('.sound').removeClass('muted, sound2, sound3');
        }

  };

  //Time format converter - 00:00
  var timeFormat = function(seconds) {
    var m = Math.floor(seconds / 60) < 10 ? "0" + Math.floor(seconds / 60) : Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(seconds - (m * 60)) < 10 ? "0" + Math.floor(seconds - (m * 60)) : Math.floor(seconds - (m * 60));
    return m + ":" + s;
  };
});
```

```css
/** CODIGO NUEVO *****************/

.speed li {
  position: relative;
}

.speed li.selected::after {
  content: "·";
  color: #00ffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 36px;
}

:-webkit-full-screen .control div.btnFS::after {
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/41D.svg);
}

:-moz-full-screen .control div.btnFS::after {
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg);
}

:-ms-fullscreen .control div.btnFS::after {
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg);
}

:fullscreen .control div.btnFS::after {
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/3ue.svg);
}

/* hay algo más de código nuevo abajo junto a .sound2 */

/** CODIGO ORIGINAL **************/


/* video container */

.videoContainer {
  width: 600px;
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
  color: #ccc;
}


/* video caption css */

.caption {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #1F1F1F;
  /* fallback */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
}


/*** VIDEO CONTROLS CSS ***/


/* control holder */

.control {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  /*height: 13%;*/
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
}


/* control top part */

.topControl {
  flex: 1;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  psoition:relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}


/* control bottom part */

.btmControl {
  height: 100%;
  clear: both;
  background: #1F1F1F;
  /* fallback */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #242424 50%, #1F1F1F 50%, #171717 100%);
  display: flex;
}

.control .btn {
  width: 20px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.control .btn::after {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin:5%;
  display: block;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-position: center center;
  
}

.control div.btnPlay::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/41B.svg);
}


/*
.control div.paused{
}
*/

.control div.paused::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/42D.svg);
}

.control div.spdText {
  width: 1em;
  height: 5px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  position: relative;
  font-size: .8em;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: #29303b;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .9);
  top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-family: arial;
}

.speed {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.speed-title {
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: none;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29)
}

.speed li {
  padding: 6px;
}
.speed .btn-speed{
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.speed .btn-speed:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.spdText:hover .speed {
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  max-height: 300px;
  transition: max-height 1s;
  left: 0pxpx;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,.4);
  color: white;
  top: 0px;
  transform: translate(0,-100%);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.control div.selected {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ccc;
}
.control div.sound {
  padding:8px !important;
  width:25px;
}
.control div.sound:before {
  content:"";
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 50%;
    top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.control div.sound::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/425.svg);
  
}

/* código nuevo */
.control div.sound3::after{
    content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/41u.svg);
  
  
}
/* .control div.sound3::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/42Q.svg);
} */

/* código nuevo */
.control div.sound2::after {
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/40h.svg);
 
  
}


.control div.muted::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/41i.svg);

}

.control div.btnFS {
  float: right;
}

.control div.btnFS::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(http://svgshare.com/i/41C.svg);
}


/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */


/* Progress bar */

.progress {
  width: 85%;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.progress span {
  height: 100%;
    border-radius:5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
}

.timeBar {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 0;
  background: #2EB3D0;
}

.bufferBar {
  z-index: 5;
  width: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}


/* time and duration */

.time {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 12px;
  width:100px;
}


/* VOLUME BAR CSS */


/* volume bar */

.volume {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 4px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  background:rgba(255, 255, 255,.2)
}

.volumeBar {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  z-index: 10;
}


/* OTHERS CSS */


/* video screen cover */

.loading,
#init {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
}

#init {
  background: url(bigplay.png) no-repeat 50% 50% !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Content -->
<section id="wrapper">

  <div class="videoContainer">

    <video id="myVideo" controls preload="auto" poster="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/x676X3ak3wo/maxresdefault.jpg" width="600" height="350">
   <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="http://demo.inwebson.com/html5-video/iceage4.webm" type="video/webM" />
   <source src="http://demo.inwebson.com/html5-video/iceage4.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
   <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
 </video>
    <div class="caption">This is HTML5 video with custom controls</div>
    <div class="control">

      <div class="btmControl">
        <div class="btnPlay btn" title="Play/Pause video"></div>
        <!--<div class="btnStop btn" title="Stop video"></div>-->
        <div class="spdText btn"><span id="current-speed">x1</span>
          <ul class="speed">
            <li class="speed-title">Speed</li>
            <li data-speed="3" class="btn-speed btnx3">x3</li>
            <li data-speed="2" class="btn-speed btnx2">x2</li>
            <li data-speed="1" class="btn-speed btnx1 selected">x1</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <!--<div class="btnx1 btn text selected" title="Normal speed">x1</div>
   <div class="btnx3 btn text" title="Fast forward x3">x3</div>-->

        <div class="topControl">
          <div class="progress">
            <span class="bufferBar"></span>
            <span class="timeBar"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="time">
            <span class="current"></span> /
            <span class="duration"></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        
        <!--<div class="btnLight lighton btn" title="Turn on/off light"></div>-->
        <div class="sound sound2 btn" title="Mute/Unmute sound"></div>
        <div class="volume" title="Set volume">
          <span class="volumeBar"></span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="btnFS btn" title="Switch to full screen"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="loading"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```